# unionize 32 bit struct with uint32_t and GCC atomic instructions

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, struct, unions

In a multithreaded program that was written I have some performance problems with very high lock contention.

I have solved this issue by having a few flags within an 32 bit unsigned integer.

currently I just bit shift the values in a temporary variable and then atomically write it.

But I don`t really like to remember the exact amount of bit shifts or where exactly what flag resides.

So I have been wondering if I could just make a union with a uint32_t and the struct with my bitflags with the same size, couldn`t I acces the bitflags by the struct and atomically write it as a uint32_t?

below is the code on how I`d like it to work. It does work but I am unsure on whether this is allowed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct atomic_flags {
    unsigned int        flags1       : 2;
    unsigned int        flags2       : 2;
    unsigned int        flags3       : 2;
    unsigned int        flags4       : 2;
    unsigned int        flags5       : 8;
    unsigned int        reserved     : 16;
}atomic_flags;

union data {
    atomic_flags    i;
    uint32_t        q;
} data;



int main() {
    union data      test1;
    union data      test2;

    test1.i.flags1 = 1;
    test1.i.flags2 = 2; 
    test1.i.flags3 = 3;
    test1.i.flags4 = 2;
    test1.i.flags5 = 241;
    test1.i.reserved = 1337;

    printf("%u\n", test1.q);

    __atomic_store_n(&test2.q, test1.q, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);

    printf("test1 flags1: %u\n", test1.i.flags1);
    printf("test1 flags2: %u\n", test1.i.flags2);
    printf("test1 flags3: %u\n", test1.i.flags3);
    printf("test1 flags4: %u\n", test1.i.flags4);
    printf("test1 flags5: %u\n", test1.i.flags5);
    printf("test1 reserved: %u\n", test1.i.reserved);

    printf("test2 flags1: %u\n", test2.i.flags1);
    printf("test2 flags2: %u\n", test2.i.flags2);
    printf("test2 flags3: %u\n", test2.i.flags3);
    printf("test2 flags4: %u\n", test2.i.flags4);
    printf("test2 flags5: %u\n", test2.i.flags5);
    printf("test2 reserved: %u\n", test2.i.reserved);

}
```

or maybe this is even possible?

```
__atomic_store_n(&test2.i.flags1, 2, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
```

Comment: Works for me : http://ideone.com/AVmpEn

Comment: yes it does. but it if works doesn`t mean it should work... not in c anyway

Comment: *Whether atomic types are permitted for bit-fields (6.7.2.1).* is implementation defined. What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc, `__atomic_store_n()` is a compiler build in. can you tell me where you get this information?

Comment: [In the compiler documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Implementation.html) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is implementation defined.

If you want to make all the masking and shifting easier and to reduce the likelihood of mistakes, then a sturdier (but uglier) way would be enlist the preprocessor to help you out:

```
/*
 * widths of the bitfields; these values can be changed independently of anything
 * else, provided that the total number of bits does not exceed 32.
 */
#define FLAG_flag1_BITS  2
#define FLAG_flag2_BITS  2
#define FLAG_flag3_BITS  2
#define FLAG_flag4_BITS  2
#define FLAG_flag5_BITS  8
/* Macro evaluating to the number of bits in the named flag */
#define FLAG_BITS(flagname) (FLAG_ ## flagname ## _BITS)

/*
 * Positions of the flags in the overall bitmask; these adapt to the flag widths
 * above, but a new macro (with the same pattern) will be needed if a bitfield
 * is added.
 */
#define FLAG_flag1_SHIFT 0
#define FLAG_flag2_SHIFT (FLAG_flag1_SHIFT + FLAG_flag1_BITS)
#define FLAG_flag3_SHIFT (FLAG_flag2_SHIFT + FLAG_flag2_BITS)
#define FLAG_flag4_SHIFT (FLAG_flag3_SHIFT + FLAG_flag3_BITS)
#define FLAG_flag5_SHIFT (FLAG_flag4_SHIFT + FLAG_flag4_BITS)
/* Macro evaluating to the position of the named flag in the overall bitfield */
#define FLAG_SHIFT(flagname) (FLAG_ ## flagname ## _SHIFT)

/* evaluates to a bitmask for selecting the named flag's bits from a bitfield */
#define FLAG_MASK(flagname) \
    ((~(((uint32_t) 0xffffffff) << FLAG_BITS(flagname))) << FLAG_SHIFT(flagname))
/* evaluates to a bitfield having the specified flag set to the specified value */
#define FLAG(flagname, v) ((v << FLAG_SHIFT(flagname)) & FLAG_MASK(flagname))

/* macro to set the specified flag in the specified bitfield to the specified value */
#define SET_FLAG(flagname, i, v) \
    do { i = (i & ~FLAG_MASK(flagname)) | FLAG(flagname, v); } while (0)
/* macro to retrieve the value of the specified flag from the specified bitfield */
#define GET_FLAG(flagname, i) (((i) & FLAG_MASK(flagname)) >> FLAG_SHIFT(flagname))

/* usage example */
int function(uint32_t bitfield) {
    uint32_t v;

    SET_FLAG(flag2, bitfield, 1);
    v = GET_FLAG(flag5, bitfield);
}
```

Though that involves a prodigous stack of macros, it's mostly driven by the first set, that give the bitfield widths.  Substantially all of that will compile down to the same shift and mask operations that you would use anyway, as the computations will be performed mostly by the preprocessor and/or compiler.  Actual usage is very simple.

Comment: It *is* implementation defined. Standard: J.3.9.

Comment: @2501, thanks, I edited my answer to be firm about that.

Comment: while this is a good answer what is the advantage is this instead of using functions?

Comment: @rowan.G the advantage over using functions is that you avoid the overhead of calling a function.  Even an inlined function is likely to be more expensive at runtime, and a non-inlined function will be much more expensive.  You get a smaller binary, too.